# LINQ to Entities - put all fields into final result

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Let's use this query as an example (this comes from the MSDN docs):

```
ObjectSet<SalesOrderHeader> orders = context.SalesOrderHeaders;
ObjectSet<SalesOrderDetail> details = context.SalesOrderDetails;

var query =
    from order in orders
    join detail in details
    on order.SalesOrderID equals detail.SalesOrderID
    where order.OnlineOrderFlag == true
    && order.OrderDate.Month == 8
    select new
    {
        SalesOrderID = order.SalesOrderID,
        SalesOrderDetailID = detail.SalesOrderDetailID,
        OrderDate = order.OrderDate,
        ProductID = detail.ProductID
    };
```

If I wanted to put all the fields present in "order" into the final object (i.e. the select new) *in addition to the additional fields from detail*, how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query =
    from order in orders
    join detail in details
    on order.SalesOrderID equals detail.SalesOrderID
    where order.OnlineOrderFlag == true
    && order.OrderDate.Month == 8
    select new
    {
        SalesOrderHeader = order;
        SalesOrderDetail = detail;
    };
```

Comment: See my edit.  You can return a anonymous class with two properties like I did there,  or you can create a concrete class containing all fields you need and use AutoMapper or ValueInjector to map to those.

Answer (score 0):

You could either return the entire `SalesOrderHeader` object in your query, or use the `Include` method.

```
ObjectSet<SalesOrderHeader> orders = context.SalesOrderHeaders;
ObjectSet<SalesOrderDetail> details = context.SalesOrderDetails;

var query =
    from order in orders
    join detail in details
    on order.SalesOrderID equals detail.SalesOrderID
    where order.OnlineOrderFlag == true
    && order.OrderDate.Month == 8
    select new
    {
        SalesOrderID = order.SalesOrderID,
        SalesOrderDetailID = detail.SalesOrderDetailID,
        OrderDate = order.OrderDate,
        ProductID = detail.ProductID,
        Order = order
    };
```

Or using the `Include` method (Assuming your `SalesOrderHeader` class has a collection reference to the `SalesOrderDetail` class):

```
ObjectSet<SalesOrderHeader> orders = context.SalesOrderHeaders;
ObjectSet<SalesOrderDetail> details = context.SalesOrderDetails;

var query =
    (from order in orders
    where order.OnlineOrderFlag == true
    && order.OrderDate.Month == 8
    select order).Include(x => x.Details);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this?

```
            var query =
            from order in orders
            join detail in details
            on order.SalesOrderID equals detail.SalesOrderID
            where order.OnlineOrderFlag == true
            && order.OrderDate.Month == 8
            select new
            {
                SalesOrderID = order.SalesOrderID,
                SalesOrderDetailID = detail.SalesOrderDetailID,
                OrderDate = order.OrderDate,
                ProductID = detail.ProductID,
                Order = order
            };
```